# Update Mysql from Curl using php

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I have a php curl script

```
$ch = curl_init();
$fp = fopen("cache/temp_file.txt", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://upload.wistia.com" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'progressCallback');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, (1024*1024*512));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result; 
fwrite($fp, $result);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

which returns a string

```
 $result={"id":5966875,"name":"php3il8M4","type":"Video","created":"2014-02-18T10:00:57+00:00","updated":"2014-02-18T10:00:57+00:00","duration":10.29,"hashed_id":"772ecmi61h","description":"","progress":0.0,"status":"queued","thumbnail":{"url":"http://embed.wistia.com/deliveries/a351871a559000f83c39f3e84b33a491c5e5224a.jpg?image_crop_resized=100x60&video_still_time=5","width":100,"height":60}}
```

I would like to only write to mysql the value after the "name":" eg. php3il8M4

And update my mysql db eg

```
 UPDATE $table SET code='$name' WHERE id=$id
```

I'm not sure what is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use as

```
$data = json_decode($result,true);
$name = $data["name"];
```

Here `$name` will contain the name and you can use it in the query

Comment: cannot believe it.. o_O

Comment: you were the first ;)

Comment: I would say sensitive mind think alike since GREAT is a very heavy weighted word for me :)